# cscope: ctrl + ']' does not work

Tags: linux, cscope

I just installed cscope-15.8b, then go to linux-next folder, run "cscope -R", after build the tags, then open a file through "Find this file" // so far so good.

Now if I want to go to a symbol's defination, by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>, it will throw error: "E433: No tags file" "E426: tag not found".

If I open the cscope.out file, I will see it looks like broken (see below). How do Ifix this?

1 ^B
        ~<Â¡dio.h
>

2 ^B
        ~<Â¡dlib.h
>

3 ^B
        ~

Answer (score 6):

The fact that the cscope.out file looks "broken" is normal, the file format is sort-of text but includes some non-printing characters as well.

Your problem is that <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> doesn't search cscope databases by default, it only searches ctags files which are entirely different. You need to `set cscopetag` in your `.vimrc` file to make it search both. From the vim help:

> If 'cscopetag' is set, the commands ":tag" and CTRL-] as well as "vim -t" 
>   will always use :cstag instead of the default :tag behavior. Effectively,
>   by setting 'cst', you will always search your cscope databases as well as
>   your tag files.  The default is off.

Comment: That means either you've selected a symbol not in the cscope database, or vim is not picking up the correct symbol. Either way, it is at least *looking* in the cscope database now

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines to your ~/.vimrc file:

```
set cscopetag
set csto=0
set tags=./tags,tags;/
cs add cscope.out
```

Better yet, copy this entire file into the ~/.vimrc file: http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim